# UIAlertView popups lock up keyboard actions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a strange behavior where if a UIAlert fires (like the one below) all subsequent keyboard or press behaviors are disabled / non responsive. Scrolling the screen still works but no action is fired from any button or keyboard presses.

```
        [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Address"
                                     message:@"The email address you entered isn't valid. Please check and try again."
                                    delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
```

Anyone experienced this behavior before and can shed some light?
Or maybe guide me in the right direction to debug it further to get to the root cause?

Thank you heaps!

Comment: You mean that after the uialertview is dismissed right.

Answer (score 0):

Did u use any UIAlertView delegates like didDismissWithButtonIndex ?

Then cross check the delegate UIAlertview delegate method implementations.

else

Simply pass the delegate as nil `delegate:nil`

```
UIAlertView *alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Address"
                                         message:@"The email address you entered isn't valid. Please check and try again."
                                        delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: The Alert view is dismissed with the press of the OK button. Then after that, no response from taps to the UIView.

Comment: Did u use any UiAlertView delegates ? like didDismissWithButtonIndex

Comment: No UiAlertView delegates. Tried the example above. Same behavior.

Comment: pass the delegate as nil delegate:nil

Comment: Yap thats what I did as per your example. Same behavior.

Comment: ho.. try any other UiAlertview samples.. create a sample app is better/